# How to add condition in filter in block of soanta admin in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

How can add condition > 2018 year in filter variable of blocks statement in yaml file in sonata admin in symfony.

created is datetime type field of table.

sonata_admin.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                class:    col-lg-3 col-xs-6          # twitter bootstrap responsive code
                position: top                        # zone in the dashboard
                type:     sonata.admin.block.stats   # block id
                settings:
                    code:  sonata.page.admin.page    # admin code - service id
                    icon:  fa-magic                  # font awesome icon
                    text:  Edited Pages
                    color: bg-yellow                 # colors: bg-green, bg-red and bg-aqua
                    filters:                         # filter values
                        createdAt: { value: > 2018 }
```

I have take this code from this documentation of sonata admin.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/dashboard.html

Comment: did you try `2018-12-31` instead of `2018`?

Comment: yes it did not work.